# Calibre library error: No such file or directory

Tags: lubuntu, calibre

Everything works great import, export, web server, connecting to all devices and reading from all my devices except from my computer. In the computer from the main program I get this error whenever I click on the book cover:

```
/mnt/1.0TB/Calibre%20Library/Astrology%20Guide%20For%20Beginners/Astrology%20Guide%20For%20Beginners%20-%20Unknown%20(6): 
No such file or directory
```

I can see the file is there and the directory is there.

• Calibre 1.39.0
• AMD 6x
• 16GB RAM
• 128GB SSD main drive: ext4
• 1TB 2nd drive format: ntfs
• Ubuntu 14.04 with Lubuntu GUI

Is anybody else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your Calibre Library database may be corrupted. Calibre has a database repair feature that can repair a corrupted Calibre Library database.

1. Click the downward arrow next to the Calibre Library button to show a dropdown menu -> select *Library Maintenance* -> *Restore database*.
2. The database restore process has three stages and may take up to one hour. A large progress bar shows the progress of each stage. It is **very important** to not interrupt the database restoration until it is complete or you may ruin your Calibre Library database, and then you will have to remove all the books in your Calibre Library and add them again to rebuild the Calibre Library database.
3. The next time that you reboot the computer all the Calibre features should work normally again.

The *Check library* feature in the screenshot tells you if there are any empty directories, extra unused files or missing book covers, etc. in your Calibre Library. This feature is for cleanup purposes, and it does not, in my experience, solve the problem when Calibre not working properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the lubuntu converting file:///mnt/1.0TB/Calibre%20Library/ to /mnt/1.0TB/Calibre%20Library/ - which is not a valid path.

This can be fixed with two lines of editing in /usr/bin/xdg-open.

Please refer http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2724944&postcount=15 for exact steps.